# How to change a text on the invoice?

Tags: magento2, orders, email, invoice

How can I change the text on my customer's invoice " **Surcharge fee** " on Magento 2

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that are the values of the product name and the SKU of this one.
So you can just change these value for the respective product on the admin panel.

Comment: Hi Rafael
The Surcharge fee is our creditcard / paypal fee. After i activated Surcharge fee under Creditcard payment.

Comment: So seems like this payment third-party module adds the fee like a product.

Comment: How can i change the text do you know that ?

Comment: Maybe there are options to change the name using the admin panel if there's not you can try to find the code for this name to change this one.

Comment: Hi again
Do you know where i can find this code?

Comment: In your folder app/code/MODULE_PACKAGE/MODULE_NAME/ folder, you can do a CTRL + F in your code editor to find.

Answer (score 0):

use `egrep -r "Surcharge fee" path/of/your/third/party/extension` to find where they create the "surcharge" product then rename it.

This is a Linux command that go through your files to find lines that match the key words. Normally you can use it if you have GIT bash installed in you windows computer. If you are using a Linux system or mac, then you can use it directly in the terminal.

Example:  `egrep -r "swatch_visual" source/vendor/magento/module-swatches/`

Output:

```
source/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Plugin/Save.php:                case 'swatch_visual':
source/vendor/magento/module-swatches/etc/adminhtml/di.xml:                <item name="swatch_visual" xsi:type="string">optionvisual</item>
source/vendor/magento/module-swatches/etc/config.xml:                    <swatch_visual>swatch_visual</swatch_visual>
```

Comment: Hi Tomy
Thank you very much for your help! Can you please tell me where i should use se egrep -r ?